# ¿Cómo puedo editar el contenido de una línea en especifico en un archivo en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystem

Básicamente tengo un archivo.txt con el siguiente contenido.

```
name=Hugo
id=good
city=Mexico
```

Si únicamente quiero editar el 'id', ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Este es el código que tengo, itero porque tal vez 'id' no siempre esté en la línea 2, es por eso que hago uso de "startwith" pero el resultado es que me agrega el nuevo 'id' al final del archivo.

```
with open("prueba.txt", "r+") as file:
     filedata = file.readlines()   

     for count in range(0, len(filedata)):
         if filedata[count].startswith("id"):
             file.write(filedata[count].replace(filedata[count], "id= "+new_id))
     file.close()
```

Comment: corrige la identación del código, pues claramente después del `with` el resto del bloque debe de estar en un nivel inferior. Por otra parte, ¿debe ser en Python? El scripting de shell permite hacer esto mucho más rápidamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías evitar el uso de `readlines()` (que para archivos grandes es ineficiente y en general, es innecesario) y probar algo como

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.FileInput("prueba.txt", inplace = 1):
    if line.startswith("id="):
        new_line = line.replace(line,"id=" + new_id)
        print(new_line)
    else:
        print(line, end='')
```

Que itera sobre el archivo y busca la línea. El print con `end=''` busca que no se añadan nuevos caracteres fin de línea (si lo quitas, pone líneas adicionales debajo de cada una del archivo original).

Referencia: [SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)